# CSS Rotation Animation Glitching On Hover

Tags: html, css, rotation

I have a question about CSS. I've coded an animation to rotate on hover. Now when I hover on it, it's glitching really much. It just begins the rotation again and again. Can someone please help. Code is here:

```css
#text {
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: lightgray;
            border-left: 0px groove;
            border-top: 0px groove;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
           
        }

         #text:hover {
            border-left: 10px groove;
            border-top: 10px groove;
            background-color: lightskyblue;
            transform: rotateY(360deg);
        } 

        #text::after {
            content: "Hover me";
            font-size: 30px;
            margin-left: 100px;
            color: black;
        }

        #text:hover::after {
            content: "If you want to know how to get started as a web developer, take a look at my youtube channel";
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="text">
       
    </div>
```

Comment: It glitches because as soon as the transform starts you aren't hovering any more.

Comment: Adding on to paulie d you probably want to add a container that handles the `hover`. The child container should receive the transform

Comment: Could you maybe visualize that? I can't follow you right now.. I've got more of these so I don't know if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paulie_D correctly stated, your `:hover` triggers the animation, but terminates the animation when your mouse leaves the `#text` element. So it resets.

There are multiple ways to fix this like this example to make a new container element that doesn't move but only triggers the animation.

```css
.text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-left: 0px groove;
  border-top: 0px groove;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.animated-card {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.animated-card:hover > .text {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.text:hover {
  border-left: 10px groove;
  border-top: 10px groove;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.text::after {
  content: "Hover me";
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: black;
}

.text:hover::after {
  content: "If you want to know how to get started as a web developer, take a look at my youtube channel";
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-card">
  <div id="text"></div>
</div>

<div class="animated-card">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div class="animated-card">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div class="animated-card">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works even with more cards in the animated-card div. :))

Comment: @LightCode Ah, you can only have one unique ID name per page (#text). I replaced ID with a class (.text) and use the `>` selector to only effect the div inside the element.